# C: Output prints values inside of a variable that is not echoed

Tags: c, echo

I have this very simple code of C that simply must echo values inside the `x` array, suprisingly, it also echoes the values inside the array `y`...

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int     i;
char    x[3]={'a','b','c'},
        y[3][2]={
             {'a','A'},
             {'b','B'},
             {'c','C'}};
void main(){
    clrscr();
    while(i<strlen(x)) cout << x[i++] << endl;
    getch();
}
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
a
A
b
B
c
C
```

Obviously, the first 3 characters are those that I really intended to echo...
But how about those following characters from array `y`?

Comment: Neither `x` nor `y` is null-terminated. Using `strlen` on it is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Oh I see `strlen` works for null-terminated arrays which are the strings...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The variable `x` is not a string, calling `strlen()` on it leads to undefined behavior.

Accessing out of bounds of the array `x` leads to undefined behavior too.

You need:

```
const char *x = "abc";
```

to make it a valid string (i.e. be terminated by `'\0'`), or:

```
const char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' };
```

but that's much more verbose so why ever do it that way? If you mean a string (and you do), write it as a string.

You can of course go the other way too, and say "it's a character array, but not a string", but then you can't use `strlen()` which requires a string:

```
const char x[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };

for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof x / sizeof *x; ++i)
  printf("%c\n", x[i]);
```

Comment: Just another thing, If I'm not wrong `x[4]` is supposed to be `\0` then why it prints `a` from `y[0][0]`?

Comment: @Daniel Character arrays are not automatically null terminated. `x[3]` (not `x[4]`) does not exist, forget about being equal to `\0`.

Comment: Yes, Sorry for that I mean `x[3]`, btw, you mean my `x` array doesn't have a `\0` at `x[3]`?

Comment: Nope. It has exactly three elements, `x[0]=='a'`,`x[1]=='b'`, and `x[2]=='c'`.

Answer (score 0):

strlen(x) will return 9 or more, it depended on when it find the end char of string '\0', so the cout will output the data out of the array x 's memory.  you can check with the memory, and step by step to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `strlen` to `sizeof`. Why?

- Arrays are not automatically ended with terminating null character `\0`
- The `strlen` function counts the offset address until `\0`
- Using `sizeof` wil thus count the size alloted for a particular array

The `strlen(x)` function is supposed to count until it finds the `\0`, and in this code, it did not.